# What is the word for something related to gender?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have the sentence

> These characters all demonstrate different types of prejudice, whether they be racial, social, or gender.

Which word should I be using in place of gender? Racial and social are both taken from race and society (as far as I know) but I'm not sure what to use in place of gender. I considered using "gender-related," but that seems like more of a work-around than a solution.

Comment: You mean like how misogynists are prejudiced against women? That's sex-based.

Comment: @tchrist I believe that would still be gender-based, since not all women are biologically female. In any case, I'd prefer to use the word for gender-based and not sex-based in this sentence.

Comment: The problem with this is not *gender*, it's *racial* and *social*. *Prejudices can be based on many things: **race**, **society**, and **gender**.* *Gender* is the only word there that ***is*** correct, the other two are wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Gender-based" can be used and will clearly communicate your intent.

Answer (score 0):

**The sentence you have is completely fine.** When there isn't an obvious adverb deriving from a noun (or even if there is) it is perfectly fine to use a compound noun. In other words it is perfectly fine to say

> He exhibited gender prejudice.

Given that, the sentence you have is an excellent formulation.

(It is also perfectly fine to talk about "race prejudice" as an alternative to "racial prejudice")

Comment: How  can it be an excellent formulation if the OP is using two adjectives and one noun? *Gender predjudice* may be fine, and *race predjudice*  may be okay also, but what noun would you use for *social* in *social predjudice*?

Comment: All of the following are acceptable: gender prejudice; race prejudice; racial prejudice; social prejudice. If any of those are acceptable then it is acceptable to refer to "types of prejudice, whether they be racial, social or gender".

Comment: I wouldn't call any formulation with a non-parallel structure "excellent".

Answer (score -1):

It appears that you are looking for adjectives, i.e., types of prejudice -- racial predjudice, social predjudice, … If so, the problem with your formulation is that *gender*, as you've used it, is a noun. Why not go with **sexual**? From M-W:

> **[sexual](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sexual)**: of, relating to, or associated with sex or the sexes

Your example:

> *These characters all demonstrate different types of prejudice, whether they be racial, social, or **sexual**.*

Comment: "sexual" is usually taken to refer to sex, not gender.

Comment: M-W: *of, relating to, or associated with … the sexes* is perfectly fine.